# Java: Writing with FileChannel to a file make the file shrink?

Tags: java, file-io, filechannel

I tried to write specific bytes to certain position of a file using FileChannel. But actually the file shrink to the last position where I write change. I do it like this:

```
    Path path = Paths.get("I://music - Copy.mp3");

    System.out.println(Files.size(path)/1024 + "KB");

    try (FileChannel chan = new FileOutputStream(path.toFile()).getChannel()) {
        chan.position(1024 * 1024);

        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        chan.write(b);

        System.out.println("Write 1KB of data");
    }

    System.out.println(Files.size(path)/1024 + "KB");
```

and this is the output I get:

```
3670KB
Write 1KB of data
1025KB
```

Can anybody tell me where it goes wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FileOutputStream truncates the file to zero length when not in append mode.  It does not overwrite a file's contents so much as it throws away the contents and starts over.  You can verify this by calling `chan.size()` after creating the channel, which will give you 0. <sup>[1]</sup>

FileChannels can be advanced past the end of a file and told to write there; this causes the file size to increase to position + bytes_written (emphasis mine):

> Setting the position to a value that is greater than the current size is legal but does not change the size of the entity. [..] *A later attempt to write bytes at such a position will cause the entity to grow to accommodate the new bytes*; the values of any bytes between the previous end-of-file and the newly-written bytes are unspecified.

So while it looks like the FileChannel is cutting off your file after writing, it is the FileOutputStream truncating to 0 length, and then the FileChannel expanding it again.

To prevent this from happening, avoid using a FileOutputStream to create a channel.  You have a Path, so you can call [`Files.newByteChannel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newByteChannel-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) or [`FileChannel.open`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) :

```
Path path = Paths.get("I://music - Copy.mp3");

System.out.println(Files.size(path)/1024 + "KB");

// pick either:
try (FileChannel chan = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
try (SeekableByteChannel chan = Files.newByteChannel(path, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
    chan.position(1024 * 1024);

    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
    chan.write(b);

    System.out.println("Write 1KB of data");
}

System.out.println(Files.size(path)/1024 + "KB");
```

---

[1] Note that programs outside the JVM, such as a file explorer, may not indicate this until you flush or close the stream.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the [FileOutputStream constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) which allows to append to the file. If you create it as above, you overwrite the content of the file.

Comment: I try it and I got the output size increased by 1 KB (3670KB-3671KB). Doesn't that just mean it is written to end of file instead on the specified position?

Answer (score 1):

try to use your `FileOutputStream` in append mode and avoid specifing current channel position:

```
new FileOutputStream(path.toFile(), true)
```

upd. didn't see the prevoius answer

Comment: Positioning the channel is not a problem - I think you should edit that out.